# How to convert string to integer list?

Tags: string-manipulation

Saying we have a string:

```
"1 2 3 4 5 6"
```

I want to convert this to integer list. First I do:

```
In[82]:= str = StringReplace["1 2 3 4 5 6", " " -> ","] // List
Out[82]= {"1,2,3,4,5,6"}
```

No I need to convert `Out[82]` to be just `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
res = ToExpression @ StringSplit["1 2 3 4 5 6", " "]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

```
 Head /@ res
```

{Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer}

**Revision 1**

If the substrings are separated by whitespace, one can omit the 2nd argument:

```
ToExpression @ StringSplit["1 2 3 4 5 6"]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Answer (score 16):

For performance fiends:

I had an application that had this very need for some huge sets of long integer strings.

*kguler*'s solution is certainly the canonical way, and quite quick, as is *Felix*'s version (I was actually surprised on that one). *eldo*'s solution is probably what most would come up with, but in performance-intensive scenarios the `StringSplit` is a killer. This is what I use for integer string to digit list conversion:

```
toDigs=With[{s = Subtract[ToCharacterCode[#], 48]}, Pick[s, UnitStep@s, 1]]&;
```

(n.b.: If the integer string is sans spaces, just `Subtract[ToCharacterCode[#], 48]&` suffices, with a nice speed bump.)

On large strings, the performance advantage can be orders of magnitude:
[image]

Even on relatively small integer strings it has advantages:

[image]

Comment: Great method!  I miss your contributions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - That means much coming from you! I'm still here, just been quite busy in semi-retirement herding some startups...

Answer (score 12):

```
FromDigits /@ StringSplit["1 2 3 4 5 6"]
ToExpression@StringSplit["1 2 3 4 5 6"]
StringCases["1 2 3 4 5 6", ns : NumberString :> FromDigits[ns]]
ToExpression@StringCases["1 2 3 4 5 6", NumberString]
```

all give

```
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} *)
```

Comment: First is close to fastest possible using native MMA, better than twice as fast as accepted, and no upvotes? Fixed: +1

Answer (score 11):

```
Flatten[ImportString["1 2 3 4 5 6", "Table"]]
```

> {1,2,3,4,5,6}

```
Head /@ %
```

> {Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer}

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
str = "1 2 3 4 5 6"
Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["Integer"]][str]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Answer (score 4):

```
ToExpression["{" <> StringReplace["1 2 3 4 5 6", " " -> ","] <> "}"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReplaceAll` and `DeleteCases`:

```
str /. x_ :> DeleteCases[ToExpression@Characters[x], Null]

(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}*)
```

Another way, using `StringCases` and `DigitCharacter`:

```
StringCases[str, ns : DigitCharacter :> FromDigits[ns]] // RepeatedTiming

(*{9.59658*10^-6, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}*)
```