# Characters to numbers

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion

I have an string `"000101"`.

I know that `Characters` change it to `{"0","0","0","1","0","1"}`.

I want to move over this list and read its member as *integer numbers*. How can i do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Closely related: [type conversions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136476/5478)

Comment: [How to convert string to integer list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78965/106) is also closely related.

Answer (score 7):

```
v = ToExpression /@ StringSplit["000101", ""]
```

yields:

```
{0,0,0,1,0,1}

ToExpression["000101"]
```

yields:

```
101
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming there are only digits in a string:

```
ToCharacterCode["123456789"] - 48
```

or

```
"123456789" // StringCases[i : DigitCharacter :> ToExpression[i]]
```

or

```
"123456789" // Characters // ToExpression
```

Answer (score 3):

```
FromDigits /@ Characters @ "000101"
```

> {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}

Comment: Nicer version than what I posted (now deleted)