# Efficient conversion from string to number

Tags: performance-tuning, string-manipulation

Is there a way to convert a list of string to numbers faster than `ToExpression`?

```
str = ToString /@ RandomReal[100, 1000];
ToExpression@str; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.007714 *)
```

Related: [How to convert string to integer list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78965/how-to-convert-string-to-integer-list)

**Edit** Thanks to J.M. who pointed to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1744/18767):

```
  Internal`StringToDouble/@str; // AbsoluteTiming // First
 (* 0.000834 *)
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1744)?

Comment: @J.M. Wow, no I had not! Probably hard to beat...

Answer (score 6):

I'd just like to point out the J.M.'s answer is also best if you have ints, since `Floor` is fast and listable as a cast from `Real`:

```
intStrings = RandomInteger[10000, 100000] // Map[ToString];

Floor[Internal`StringToDouble /@ intStrings] // RepeatedTiming // First

0.048

ToExpression@intStrings // RepeatedTiming // First

0.413
```

Comment: Maybe you can incorporate J.M.'s answer too (as community if you're not comfortable) so that I can accept it.